# Sending wild card as attachment

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, automation

I'm trying to execute a batch which it will send an attachment on specific dates.
This batch file (`Date.bat`) will copy the file based on current date to a new folder:

```
copy C:\test\output.csv C:\test2\output%date:~-4,4%_%date:~-10,2%_%date:~7,2%.csv
```

This `email.vbs` script will send attachment to the user:

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.Subject = "test123" 
objMessage.From = "spartan@test.com" 
objMessage.To = "test123@test.com" 
objMessage.HTMLBody = strHTML
objMessage.AddAttachment "c:\test\output.csv"

'==This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.
'==Normally you will only change the server name or IP.
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 

'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "spartan-dev"

'Server port (typically 25)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

'==End remote SMTP server configuration section==

objMessage.Send
```

For example, when I execute `Date.bat` on Friday, the Friday's attachment will be sent on next Monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Task Scheduler.

This shows how to connect to a computer and lists tasks in root folder.

```
Set TS = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
TS.Connect("Serenity")

Set rootFolder = TS.GetFolder("\")

Set tasks = rootFolder.GetTasks(0)

If tasks.Count = 0 Then 
    Wscript.Echo "No tasks are registered."
Else
    WScript.Echo "Number of tasks registered: " & tasks.Count

    For Each Task In Tasks
    A=Task.Name
    A = A & " " & Task.NextRunTime
    A = A & " " & Task.LastTaskResult
    wscript.echo A
    Next
End If
```

You can also use batchfile. See `schtasks /?`.

This is from Help listing files in a folder.

```
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.GetFolder("c:\")
   Set fc = f.Files
   For Each f1 in fc
      s = s & f1.name 
   Next
   Msgbox s
```

Comment: The problem is the file name keep changing everyweek.

Comment: Well what do you know about this filename, only file in a folder? or name follows a set pattern?

Comment: outputYYYY_MM_DD.csv. The date keep changing everyweek